# Did Albert Einstein write a computer program?

Tags: computer-science, einstein

I am curious whether or not Albert Einstein wrote a computer program. Did he write a computer program?

Comment: Well, FORTRAN was invented in 1954, Einstein died in 1955, so there is a small window.  But I agree, very few outside IBM used FORTRAN until its commercial release in 1957.

Comment: SInce von Neumann had a computer at the Institute for Advanced Study, it is highly likely that he wrote a computer program...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Very few people had written computer programs at the time of his death, 1955, and most had backgrounds in numerical analysis, and computational techniques. Programs were written in machine code in those days, or a few newer machines had an assembly language.

John von Neumann is a much better candidate for computer programming.